# Interpret string value as ruby method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, form-for

I have a FormQuestion model that stores form_for tags as strings.
I am looking to have something like the following:

```
<%= form_for(application_form) do |f| %>
  <% FormQuestion.all.each do |q| %>
    <%= q.input %>  #where q.input = "f.text_field :name"
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I get the string returned from q.input to be interpreted as the form_for ruby tag, rather than simply being printed as text on the page?

EDIT:
`eval(q.input)` was suggested, however I am looking for a safer alternative

Comment: try `<%= raw q.input %>`

Comment: @NoamHacker already tried that. It just prints the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use [send](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send) method as:

```
<%= form_for(application_form) do |f| %>
  <% FormQuestion.all.each do |q| %>
    <%= f.send(q.input) %>  #where q.input = "f.text_field :name"
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: that should probably be `f.send(q.input)`.  Also try `public_send` as `send` also has access to private methods.

Comment: but still, that's not a complete answer as @mu is too short pointed out above.  if `q.input` is an array, then that should be `f.send(*q.input)` instead.

Comment: " undefined method `f.text_field :name' "

Answer (score 0):

I would change this to either be:

```
<%= form_for(application_form) do |f| %>
  <% FormQuestion.all.each do |q| %>
    <% f.send q.type, q.name %>  #where q.type = :text_field and q.name = :name
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or else:

```
<%= form_for(application_form) do |f| %>
  <% FormQuestion.all.each do |q| %>
    <%= raw q.as_html %>  # where q.as_html = "<input name="name"></input>"
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When using f.send i get the error:  
`"undefined method ':text_field' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007ffd63658c50>
Did you mean?  text_field" ` . I get the same error for `:name`. If i remove the colons then nothing is displayed on the page.

Comment: I meant to use symbols, i..e, `:text_field` although you could use strings ('text_field'). in other words, the following are roughly equivalent. `<%= f.text_field :name %>`, `<%= f.send :text_field :name %>`, `<%= f.send 'text_field',  'name' %>`

Comment: I see I also should have written `<%= f.send q.type, q.name %>` not `<% f.send q.type, q.name %>`